# Adding legend double-y axis graph line & bars but not shown

Tags: r

I cannot make the legend show up for both variables. And I would like to remove the linetype from the legend too (see below for image)

I try this:

```
valuecolor <- "#69b3a2"
numbercolor <- rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1)

ggplot(data = ma) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Year, y = ValueUS, fill = "ValueUS"), stat = "identity", fill= valuecolor, color="black", alpha=.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = NumberUS/10, group = 1, lty = "Number US deals"), size = 1, color = numbercolor) +
  scale_y_continuous( sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name = "Number")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("ValueUS" = ValueUS)) +
  theme_ipsum()
```

But I get only one legend. See below for plot and data used:

[image]

```
dput(ma)
structure(list(Year = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"
), NumberWW = c(2676, 4228, 5279, 7440, 10135, 10814, 14722, 
14102, 14772, 16816, 20278, 24310, 26227, 30218, 33132, 39783, 
31047, 27201, 29573, 32953, 36025, 41407, 47455, 45173, 40710, 
44844, 43976, 41480, 39568, 43847, 48052, 49991, 53302, 50607, 
49327, 44926, 52000), ValueWW = c(347, 435, 506, 777, 758, 540, 
397, 400, 516, 624, 1039, 1217, 1824, 2678, 4116, 3623, 1866, 
1242, 1411, 2145, 2794, 4023, 4920, 3075, 2187, 2750, 2668, 2533, 
2536, 3960, 4779, 3646, 3777, 3393.563, 3370.106, 2817.39, 4898
), NumberUS = c(2309, 3447, 3708, 4443, 5840, 5982, 5702, 5915, 
6782, 8076, 9368, 11856, 13147, 14780, 13245, 14114, 9652, 8571, 
9272, 10744, 11436, 13019, 13999, 11731, 9466, 10191, 10536, 
10629, 10877, 12283, 12885, 13430, 15558, 14936, 17759, 15271, 
21000), ValueUS = c(305.64, 353.54, 373.17, 586.05, 466.09, 254.16, 
176.99, 185.13, 317.61, 414.7, 666.58, 750.39, 1116.22, 1816.41, 
2138.18, 1965.81, 1010.58, 520.54, 668.86, 1006.42, 1342.1, 1843.89, 
1967.06, 1215.09, 877.61, 981.8, 1247.04, 995.65, 1214.79, 2153.8, 
2417.39, 1784.77, 1761.54, 1931.81, 1887.57, 1125.82, 2587), 
    GDPUS = c(4579.6325, 4855.21625, 5236.438, 5641.5795, 5963.1445, 
    6158.12925, 6520.32725, 6858.5585, 7287.2365, 7639.74925, 
    8073.12175, 8577.5525, 9062.81675, 9631.17175, 10250.952, 
    10581.929, 10929.10825, 11456.4495, 12217.19575, 13039.197, 
    13815.583, 14474.227, 14769.8615, 14478.06675, 15048.97, 
    15599.73175, 16253.97, 16843.19575, 17550.68775, 18206.0235, 
    18695.10575, 19477.3365, 20533.0575, 21380.976, 21060.47425, 
    23315.08125, 23315.08125)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -37L))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `fill` legend for your bars gets dropped as you have overwritten the `fill` aes using `fill= valuecolor`. Drop that and your legend will show up. Also, IMHO there is no need to make use of the `lty` aes as you can use `color`. The legend titles can be set or removed via e.g. `labs`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

valuecolor <- "#69b3a2"
numbercolor <- rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1)

ggplot(data = ma) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Year, y = ValueUS, fill = "ValueUS"), stat = "identity", color = "black", alpha = .4) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Year, y = NumberUS / 10, group = 1, color = "NumberUS"), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 10, name = "Number")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("ValueUS" = valuecolor)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("NumberUS" = numbercolor)) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  labs(fill = NULL, color = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!
One further question: how can I change the numbers in the axis. If i want that they look like 1,000 and 10,000 in both y axis? or if I want to reduce the number of zeros?

Comment: You could do `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma(), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 10, name = "Number", labels = scales::label_comma()))` to a "," as thousands separator. And if you want to reduce the number of zeros you could use `scales::label_comma(scale = 1e-3)`, ie.. to scale or divide by 1000